# How can I have a series of numpy ndarrays as the input data to train a tensorflow machine learning model?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a machine learning model which predicts a single number from a series of numbers. I am using a Sequential model from the keras API of Tensorflow.

Basically my x data is a Pandas series which contains numpy ndarrays, which contain floats.
My y data is a series of numpy ndarrays of shape (1,1), so basically just a single float value.

You can imagine my dataset to look something like this:

| Index | x data (pandas series) | y data (pandas series) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `np.ndarray(shape (1209278,) )` | `np.ndarray(shape = () )` |
| 1 | `np.ndarray(shape (1211140,) )` | `np.ndarray(shape = () )` |
| 2 | `np.ndarray(shape (1418411,) )` | `np.ndarray(shape = () )` |
| 3 | `np.ndarray(shape (1077132,) )` | `np.ndarray(shape = () )` |
| ... | ... | ... |

The type of my x data and y data is, as stated above, a pandas series.
When I try to train my model using the fit function it yields this error:

*ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)*

I also tried converting the pandas series to a numpy array, but this did not help.
As it seems, the fact that I have a series of differently shaped ndarrays as my input data is the problem itself.

I don't really know what I can do, to fix this error.
Which leads me to my question:

**How can I have a series of numpy ndarrays as the input data to train a tensorflow machine learning model?**

Answer (score 0):

Pandas Data Series does not support a direct conversion to tensors.
So I would try first to convert those to **list**:

```
X = X.to_list()
Y = Y.to_list()
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not get the same error I got previously, but now I get an error like this:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PwROsj9

Comment: How have you made the train/test split?
Also, which are the shapes of each of x_train and y_train?
One final question, there is some Null values?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Splitting was done using `train_set = df.sample(frac=0.8)`, then I applied you suggestion to use `to_list`, resulting in x_train and y_train. Because I converted my data to lists, x_train and y_train do not really have a "shape" anymore. The length of both lists is in my case the same.

Comment: I think the issue might be, that the shape of my output data is like this: `shape = ()`. 
See here for example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/54835

Comment: No worries!
Okey. I think that the error could be that tf expects 2d, so what i would do is:
```
X_train = [X_train]
Y_train = [Y_train]
```

Comment: Sadly this did not change anything

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).