# How can I use a sequence of numbers to predict a single number in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a machine learning model which predicts a single number from a series of numbers. I am using a Sequential model from the keras API of Tensorflow.

You can imagine my dataset to look something like this:

| Index | x data | y data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `np.ndarray(shape (1209278,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 1 | `np.ndarray(shape (1211140,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 2 | `np.ndarray(shape (1418411,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 3 | `np.ndarray(shape (1077132,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| ... | ... | ... |

**This was my first attempt:**

I tried using a numpy ndarray which contains numpy ndarrays which finally contain floats as my xdata, so something like this:

```py
array([
    array([3.59280851, 3.60459062, 3.60459062, ..., 4.02911493])
    array([3.54752101, 3.56740332, 3.56740332, ..., 4.02837855])
    array([3.61048168, 3.62152741, 3.62152741, ..., 4.02764217])
])
```

My y data is a numpy ndarray containing floats, which looks something like this

```py
array([2.9864411, 3.0562437, ... , 2.7750807, 2.8712902], dtype=float32)
```

But when I tried to train the model using `model.fit()` it yields this error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I was able to solve this error by asking a question related to this:
[How can I have a series of numpy ndarrays as the input data to train a tensorflow machine learning model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72815591/how-can-i-have-a-series-of-numpy-ndarrays-as-the-input-data-to-train-a-tensorflo)

**My latest attempt:**
Because Tensorflow does not seem to be able to convert a ndarray of ndarrays to a tensor, I tried to convert my x data to a list of ndarrays like this:

```py
[
    array([3.59280851, 3.60459062, 3.60459062, ..., 4.02911493])
    array([3.54752101, 3.56740332, 3.56740332, ..., 4.02837855])
    array([3.61048168, 3.62152741, 3.62152741, ..., 4.02764217])
]
```

I left my y data untouched, so as a ndarray of floats.
Sadly my attempt of using a list of ndarrays instead of a ndarray of ndarrays yielded this error:

```py
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1304593, 1209278, 1407624, ...
  y sizes: 46
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

As you can see, my x data consists of arrays which all have a different shape.
But I don't think that this should be a problem.

**Question:**

My guess is that Tensorflow tries to use my list of arrays as *multiple* inputs.
[Tensorflow fit() documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

But I don't want to use my x data as multiple inputs.
Easily said I just want my model to predict a number from a sequence of numbers.
For example like this:

- array([3.59280851, 3.60459062, 3.60459062, ...]) => 2.8989773
- array([3.54752101, 3.56740332, 3.56740332, ...]) => 3.0893357
- ...

**How can I use a sequence of numbers to predict a single number in Tensorflow?**

**EDIT**
Maybe I should have added that I want to use a RNN, especially a LSTM.
I have had a look at the Keras documentation, and in their simplest example they are using a `Embedding` layer. But I don't really know what to do.

All in all I think that my question ist pretty general and should be easy to answer if you know how to tackle this problem, unlike me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried looking into RNNs? They seem like they are exactly what you want here as they are designed for predicting sequence data. https://keras.io/guides/working_with_rnns/

Comment: Hi, yes I did. To be specific, I want to use a LSTM RNN. Mayber I should have added this to my question beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# add additional dimension for lstm layer
x_train = np.asarray(train_set["x data"].values))[..., None] 
y_train = np.asarray(train_set["y data"]).astype(np.float32)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=32))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam", metrics="mse")
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,epochs=10)
```

Or with a ragged input for different sequence lengths:

```
x_train = tf.ragged.constant(train_set["x data"].values[..., None]) # add additional dimension for lstm layer
y_train = np.asarray(train_set["y data"]).astype(np.float32)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, x_train.bounding_shape()[-1]], batch_size=2, dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=32))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam", metrics="mse")
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,epochs=10)
```

Or:

```
x_train = tf.ragged.constant([np.array(list(v))[..., None] for v in train_set["x data"].values]) # add additional dimension for lstm layer
```